# Basic math question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm going back to school and haven't taken a math class in years, so I'm brushing up on the basics.

The text states $\frac{g(t + \Delta(t))^2}{2} = \frac{gt^2}{2} + \frac{g}{2}\left(2t\Delta t + \Delta t^2\right)$.

(Sorry for the lack of formatting. I'll probably get slammed, but I couldn't figure it out on my phone...)

My question is: how did they arrive at that conclusion? I've spent the last four hours trying to work it out to no avail. I'm very discouraged at this point, so any clarification would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Well, by using $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$, then

$$\frac{g (t + \Delta t)^2}{2} = \frac{g}{2}[t^2 + 2t \Delta t + \Delta^2t]= \frac{gt^2}{2} + \frac{g}{2}[2t \Delta t + \Delta^2 t ]$$

Actually, $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ is an algebraic identity . But let see it geometrically what it means. consider the following square

[image]

Let $A$ denote the total area of the square, then $A = (a+b)(a+b) = (a+b)^2$ and let $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ denote the area of the little squares, then
$A_1 = ba$, $A_2 = a^2$, $A_3 = ab$ and $A_4 = b^2$.

But,

$$ A = A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4  \implies ba + a^2 + ab + b^2 = (a+b)^2 $$

$$ \therefore (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 $$

Comment: your answer is good . I have liked it .

Comment: Minor typo:  the $\Delta^2t$'s should be $(\Delta t)^2$.  (Actually, I wonder if the OP's difficulty is with the meaning of $\Delta t$, which he writes as if it were a function, $\Delta(t)$, on the left hand side in the problem.)

Comment: you are confusing the asker with this square.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Could you leave out that last step (in the original problem) or is the end result somehow the "best" way to write it?

Answer (score 2):

use the following formula and you will get your answer :

$(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2 $